# Memory usage in Profiler much less than on actual device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, memory, profiler

Today, I attached the memory profiler to my physical S7 edge and after 5 minutes I had an average memory usage of 62 MB. The Google pre-launch reports, on the other hand, shows a usage between 100 and 300 MB. Does anyone know where this huge difference comes from?

Answer (score 2):

It mention in the google documents   [How memory is counted ?](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler)

> When using devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, the
>   Memory Profiler also shows some false-positive native memory usage in
>   your app that actually belongs to the profiling tools. Up to 10MB of
>   memory is added for ~100k Java objects. In a future version of the
>   IDE, these numbers will be filtered out of your data.